# PHP shell_exec update output as script is running

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm using a script to get files from my server. I'm using aria2 to download the files quickly and it works great but is there a way when the script is running to output what is happening in the command.

For example when you run this command via command line you get updates every couple of seconds

```
$output = shell_exec('aria2c http://myserver.com/myfile.rar');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

**I get these outputs:**

```
[#f6a7c4 9.5MiB/1.7GiB(0%) CN:15 SD:5 DL:431KiB ETA:1h9m9s]

[#f6a7c4 52MiB/1.7GiB(2%) CN:23 SD:7 DL:0.9MiB ETA:30m19s]

[#f6a7c4 141MiB/1.7GiB(8%) CN:26 SD:4 DL:1.7MiB ETA:15m34s]
```

The script only shows me this data once it has finished executing, Which can be upto 5+ minutes so i would like to know whats going on if possible?

**Ive tried adding the following:**

```
ob_start();
--Get URL for Files and show URL on screen
ob_flush();
--Start downloading file
ob_flush();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to open a process descriptor handle to read asyncronously with `proc_open()` and read from this stream using `stream_get_contents()`.

Your tool to download flushes the progress with a `\r` char at the end, which overwrites the actual line because there is no following `\n` newline char.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Please refer to these functions to find examples of code on php.net or google.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use `proc_open`, instead of `shell_exec()`...:

```
<?php
    $cmd = 'wget http://192.168.10.30/p/myfile.rar';
    $pipes = array();
    $descriptors = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("pipe", "w"),
    );
    $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes) or die("Can't open process $cmd!");

    $output = "";
    while (!feof($pipes[2])) {
        $read = array($pipes[2]);
        stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, 0);
        if (!empty($read)) {
            $output .= fgets($pipes[2]);
        }
        # HERE PARSE $output TO UPDATE DOWNLOAD STATUS...
        print $output;
    }
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);
    ?>
```

*UPDATE*: Yes, sorry, corrected a couple of errors... :-(

And, be sure "aria2" executable is in your php environment PATH... To be on the safe side, you should specify it's full path on your system...

Comment: Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www2/html/download.php on line 9

Warning: stream_select(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /var/www2/html/download.php on line 11

Warning: stream_select() [function.stream-select]: No stream arrays were passed in /var/www2/html/download.php on line 11

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www2/html/download.php on line 13

Comment: still seem to be getting same errors, i tried replacing aria2c with wget and same errors. Im not actually sure about aria2c is executable by php environment path, When i use shell_exec it runs fine, does that mean its ok ? thanks for the help really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok. Not it works for me... Please note I now read from $pipes[2], since wget writes to stderr...

Comment: ok thanks it seems to work with wget but cant see to get aria2 working, Do i need to change $pipes[2]?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43313/discussion-between-marcos-and-exoon)