# How to Wait for completion of shell commands execution in PHP?

Tags: php

i am executing long running shell commands using PHP. in a single php file i am calling a series of shell_exec function to execute long runnable commands.

What's the problem is ,that i am getting a response before those shell commands executed. I think those shell_exec calls are queuing and running in background.

What i need is php should not send me a response until completely execute a all shell commands.

I tried both exec and shell_exec function but same thing is happening.

Comment: That is not the case. Neither `exec` nor `shell_exec` are asynchronous. Try it yourself. Run `exec("sleep 15");` and see how long it takes to finish.

Comment: i tried executing exec("sleep 15"); its exactly working. i will wait for 15 seconds and then php is returning its response. but in my case its not working, PHP initiates all the shell_commands and its returning response, its not waiting for those for completion. i dont know whats the reason.

Comment: Well it sounds like the problem is with your commands rather than your PHP code then.

Comment: i am executing commands like "adb install" and  "adb push". is there any way to control the shell commands execution in PHP like...creating own process and execute shell commands within it and wait for it to complete are like that.

Comment: Are you sure the commands are actually succeeding? What is the exit code?

Comment: yes commands are succeeding... exit code is zero

Comment: Are the commands actually doing the expected thing then (just after the PHP script has finished)?

Comment: yes commands actually doing what i  expected.... but all those things are happening after the PHP response came.

Comment: And if you execute the commands in a shell it doesn't return to the prompt until all the expected actions have completed? Hmm, that's very weird. I wonder if `adb` does something strange if it detects it is running from a non-interactive shell.

Comment: if i run the same commands directly in the shell its waiting until the complete actual action takes place.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with output buffering http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

So first you would call:

`ob_start();`

and once you're done with all your processes you'd call

`ob_end_flush();`

Provided you know the exec script has finished, either through a callback or sync.

Edit: This seems to be related to your processes, and might be a better way to spawn external processes as you get a descriptor for the async:

[PHP shell_exec update output as script is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614557/php-shell-exec-update-output-as-script-is-running)

Answer (score 0):

shell_exec waits for command, so, problem is, as u think, you're calling it into background, maybe a nohup?.

Also, de ob start, should doesn't work, for the same reason.

The only solution, i see, is to debug/modify your commands called via shell_exec and ensure doesn't run into background.

Comment: Also, maybe is a simple error, like you're executing somethin like shell_exec("wget www.web.com?param1=2&param2=x"); this causes a wget get into background (and with a wrong url), because the &

Comment: Without the exact commands you're running, i can't help more, sorry, i'm just guessing :)

Comment: i am executing commands like "adb install" and "adb push" etc...i am calling php script from andoird application.